# Sum whenever another column changes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a `df` with VENDOR, INVOICE and AMOUNT. I want to create a column called ITEM, which starts at 1, and when the invoice number changes it will change to 2 and so on.

I tried using `cumsum`, but it isn't actually working - and it makes sense not to work. The way I wrote the code it will sum 1 for the same invoice and start over when the invoice changes.

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

data['ITEM_drop'] = 1
s = data['INVOICE'].ne(data['INVOICE'].shift()).cumsum()
data['ITEM'] = data.groupby(s)['ITEM_drop'].cumsum()
```

Output:

```
VENDOR   INVOICE   AMOUNT   ITEM_drop   ITEM
  A        123       10       1           1
  A        123       12       1           2
  A        456       44       1           1
  A        456       5        1           2
  A        456       10       1           3
  B        999       7        1           1 
  B        999       1        1           2
```

And what I want is:

```
VENDOR   INVOICE   AMOUNT   ITEM_drop   ITEM
  A        123       10       1           1
  A        123       12       1           1
  A        456       44       1           2
  A        456       5        1           2
  A        456       10       1           2
  B        999       7        1           3 
  B        999       1        1           3
```

Comment: You already have it. It's `s`: `data['ITEM'] = s`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice that before!

Comment: so far it seems your INVOICE column is sorted. thus you could do: `df.assign(ITEM = df.INVOICE.astype('category').cat.codes + 1)`